# Spring Boot 2 with actuator

Tags: spring-boot

i'm using spring boot 2.0.0.M3 with the spring-boot-starter-actuator. I enabled two health checks:

```
management.health.diskspace.enabled=true
management.health.mongo.enabled=true
```

The healt check beans are created by the auto configure, but not the `HealthMvcEndpoint`. The response of `localhost:8080/health` is 404.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Mhm do the actuator project works with reactive and webflux?
Ok found this issue:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the documentations for 2.0.0M the actuator endpoints have been prefixed with `/application` so they become `/application/health` instead.

You should also be able to see all this in the `info` logs about the endpoints, when booting up your application

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints

also an actual release note about it: 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0.0-M1-Release-Notes#actuator-default-mapping

Comment: Thanks for the answer and uppdate about the `application` prefix, but no difference the endpoint is not registered.
Yes i know i will see all info about the endpoint and there is nothing in the logs.

Comment: From what you have supplied of information about your problem it's impossible to say what could be wrong. More detail about dependencies, application.properties and application structure is needed. One thing comes to mind though; have you made sure that the actuator servlet is running the same port (8080) as the main application.

Comment: I found the issue actuator doesn't work with reactive web flux. Just with spring mvc.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7970

Comment: @SirWayne ... It's really sad, becouse I'm fallowing a Spring Boot starting from Packt and it is assuming it works fine with web flux

Comment: Friends, can anybody confirm the url should be as /actautor or /application in spring boot 2. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html

Comment: Actuator endpoint prefix is `/actuator` for spring boot `2.0.0-RELEASE`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using webflux+springboot 2.0.2.RELEASE.
Checking the logs I found that it is actuallu under /actuator now.

so: `http://localhost:8080/actuator/health` will work

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your application.properties file:

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
```

The actuator endpoints will now be '/health'

Answer (score 0):

Include the **spring-boot-starter-web** dependency in your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```